Add JsonArray in an OpenEdge JsonObject,Progress-4GL
I am trying to recreate this JSON but in my code the array leaves it out of the JSON object. I have not seen it in the documentation of how to keep it inside. This is my code in it's current state and how it exits. I've also added how I want it to look.
How I want it to look.
{
    "data": [
        {
          "external_id": "AlphaNumeric",
          "external_branch_id": "AlphaNumeric",
          "name": "Super Awesome Guy",
          "cellphone": "String_int",
          "gender": "(m/f only)",
          "autosuggest": int,
          "campaigns": [
               {
                    "name": "Super Awesome Campaign"
               }
          ]
        }
    ]
}

My code:
/* Create new JsonObjects */
oJson     = NEW JsonObject().
oJsonData = NEW JsonObject().

aJson1stTable = NEW JsonArray().
aJson2ndTable = NEW JsonArray().
//oJson:READ(TEMP-TABLE data:HANDLE).

oJson:Add("data", aJson1stTable).
aJson1stTable:READ(TEMP-TABLE data:HANDLE).
oJson:Add("campaigns", aJson2ndTable).
aJson2ndTable:READ(TEMP-TABLE campaigns:HANDLE).
//oJson:READ(TEMP-TABLE campaigns:HANDLE).

/* Write the JSON string to a character variable */ 
oJson:Write(jSon_string,TRUE). 

How are you getting it out:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "external_id": "97816",
      "external_branch_id": "1",
      "external_user_id": null,
      "name": "AIDE RODRIGUEZ MAR",
      "force_delete_rs": false,
      "rs": null,
      "cellphone": "1111111111",
      "telephone": "5555102609",
      "email": "lizmar056@gmail.com",
      "customer_category": null,
      "gender": "M",
      "birthday": "2001-11-09",
      "autosuggest": false,
      "force_delete_addresses": false
    }
  ],
  "campaigns": [
    {
      "name": "Bono Activo"
    }
  ]
}

If you can tell me how I should do it and where I was wrong.

You are adding the campaigns property to the top-level object
oJson:Add("campaigns", aJson2ndTable).

You need to add it to aJson1stTable instead
